# Conditional Statement to re-start Python script based on response from POST request

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a python script where I am sending a POST request for data to a server.  I am expecting a particular response which indicates there is data in the response.  If I do not receive this response, how can I restart my script/go to the beginning of it.  The script is wrapped in a function which allows it to run every minute.

I would like to return to the beginning of my function if my response isn't as expected.

Script:

```
import sched, time, requests, jsonpickle, arcpy, requests, json, datetime
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
def do_something(sc):

        data2 = jsonpickle.decode((f2.read()))
        Start = datetime.datetime.now()
        # Start = datetime.datetime.strftime(data2['QueryRequest']['LastUpdatedDate'])
        DD = datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
        earlier = Start - DD
        earlier_str = earlier.strftime('X%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S').replace('X0','X').replace('X','')
        data2["QueryRequest"]['LastUpdatedDate'] = str(earlier_str)
        data2 = jsonpickle.encode(data2)
        BulkyItemInfo = " "
        spatial_ref = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)
        lastpage = 'false'
        startrow = 0
        newquery = 'new'
        pagesize = 100

        url2 = "URL"
        headers2 = {'Content-type': 'text/plain', 'Accept': '/'}

    while lastpage == 'false':
        r2 = requests.post(url2, data=data2, headers=headers2)
        print r2.text
        decoded2 = json.loads(r2.text)
        f2 =open('C:\Users\GeoffreyWest\Desktop\Request.json')
        data2 = jsonpickle.decode((f2.read()))
        if decoded2['Response']['LastPage'] == 'false':
            data2['QueryRequest']['PageSize'] = pagesize
            startrow = startrow + data2['QueryRequest']['PageSize']
            data2['QueryRequest']['StartRowNum'] = startrow
            data2['QueryRequest']['NewQuery'] = 'false'
            data2 = jsonpickle.encode(data2)
            print startrow
        else:
            lastpage = 'true'

    print json.dumps(decoded2, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

    items = []
    for sr in decoded2['Response']['ListOfServiceRequest']['ServiceRequest']:#Where response is successful or fails
```

Output for successful response:

```
{
    "status": {
        "code": 311,
        "message": "Service Request Successfully Queried.",
        "cause": ""
    },
    "Response": {
        "LastPage": "false",
        "NumOutputObjects": "100",
        "ListOfServiceRequest": {
            "ServiceRequest": [
                {
```

Output for unsuccessful response:

```
{"status":{"code":311,"message":"Service Request Successfully Queried.","cause":""},"Response":{"LastPage":"true","NumOutputObjects":"0","ListOfServiceRequest":{}}}
```

Comment: If it's unsuccessful, call the function again.

Comment: Why do not use while loop until response became successful? And just call the function inside loop

Comment: Yes, I will just call the function in the loop if it returns an unsuccessful output.

Comment: I don't usually write/deal with functions a lot, so thank you @Brobin and Sergius